# GitLab Activity section shows recent changes with a big delay

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

Since I have upgraded our GitLab CE to 8.6
It stopped showing the recent changes for example in Activity section
also not showing latest commits for MR's.

Right now running the up to date version (8.6.4) still the same issue.

As you can see below the Check looks fine

```
root@server:~# sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:check
Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 2.6.12 ? ... OK (2.6.12)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
hooks directories in repos are links: ... 
Administrator / projectX ... ok
Running /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files: 
    /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories: OK
    /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Test redis-cli executable: redis-cli 2.8.24
Send ping to redis server: PONG
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking Reply by email ...

Reply by email is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking Reply by email ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP is disabled in config/gitlab.yml

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Git configured with autocrlf=input? ... yes
Database config exists? ... yes
All migrations up? ... yes
Database contains orphaned GroupMembers? ... no
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Uploads directory setup correctly? ... yes
Init script exists? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
Init script up-to-date? ... skipped (omnibus-gitlab has no init script)
projects have namespace: ... 
Administrator / projectX ... yes
Redis version >= 2.8.0? ... yes
Ruby version >= 2.1.0 ? ... yes (2.1.8)
Your git bin path is "/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git"
Git version >= 2.7.3 ? ... yes (2.7.4)
Active users: 21

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

Tried to:

1. Restart GitLab
2. Clear cache

*UPDATE*
version upgrade to the latest version has helped

Comment: Solution from here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2675  didn't help: Verify the link "hooks -> /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks" in diretory of repository.

Comment: it's about 2 minutes (probably exactly 2 minutes)

Comment: right after making any changes (e.g. pushing a new branch). I run gitlab-rake cache:clear and it still waited for 2 minutes to show the change. So it looks like it's related to cache issues

Comment: [Gitlab issue 588 ?](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/588)

Comment: @Thomas thanks, but my issue is about delay (2 minutes) and not about not seeing changes at all

Comment: Have you tried to relaunch the create-hooks script ? `sudo -u git -H /home/git/gitlab-shell//bin/create-hooks`

Comment: @MaëlLavault didn't help (the path in my case was: /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/bin/create-hooks

Comment: Just upgraded to the latest version (8.6.5) and everything is back on track..all good.

Comment: @bakytn, could you please edit the question to say the problem was solved by the upgrade?

Comment: to properly mark a question as answered on SO, please post an answer and mark it as the definitive answer to the question instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the next version of the software did help.